# Why can Cloud Composer 2 not connect to Redis during environment generation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have tried multiple times to create a new Cloud Composer 2 environment. While creating a Cloud Composer 1 environment worked completely fine, this keeps on failing. From what I can see in the logs it appears that airflow-worker cannot connect to Redis. I already made sure the Cloud Composer service account has sufficient rights. What else could be the cause of this?

Comment: could you share the error you get?

Comment: Running into similar issue, did you figure this out ?
Error is 
consumer: Cannot connect to redis://airflow-redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379/0: Error 110 connecting to airflow-redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local:6379. Connection timed out..